# border-image with jQuery resize cross-platform?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jQuery to resize divs to fit the browser view-port, and I'm able to get it to be the right size in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. However the border-image only appears in Chrome for some reason.

This is what I have in the CSS:

```
div.header, div.sidebar, div.content {
    border-width:          10px;
    -webkit-border-image:  url(images/borderimage.gif) 10 10 10 10 stretch stretch;
       -moz-border-image:  url(images/borderimage.gif) 10 10 10 10 stretch stretch;
            border-image:  url(images/borderimage.gif) 10 10 10 10 stretch stretch;
}
```

And this is what I have script-wise: (The numbers being subtracted are for formatting)

```
$("#over").css("height", document.documentElement.clientHeight+"px");
$("#over").css("width", document.documentElement.clientWidth+"px");

var overinner = $("div.overallinner");
$(".header").css("width", overinner.innerWidth()+"px");
$(".content").css("width", (overinner.innerWidth()-290)+"px");

var headr = $("div.header");
$("#head").css("width", headr.innerWidth()-5+"px");
$("#head").css("height", headr.innerHeight()-5+"px");

var sideb = $("div.sidebar");
$("#side").css("width", sideb.innerWidth()-5+"px");
$("#side").css("height", sideb.innerHeight()-5+"px");

var contn = $("div.content");
$("#cont").css("width", contn.innerWidth()-10+"px");
$("#cont").css("height", contn.innerHeight()-+"px");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: (1) Is the jQuery code run when the page first loads (as well as when the browser is resized)? (2) Does the border image display correctly in Chrome, Firefox, and IE before resizing the browser?

Comment: The jQuery script doesn't work when I put it in the head, but when I run it at the end of the body, it works, and the image-border never works in IE or Firefox, put works before and after resizing in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery code isn't the problem. This is a matter of CSS browser support.

**Firefox**

In Firefox, you have to specify a `border-style` as well as a `border-width`, for `border-image` styles to work.

```
div.header, div.sidebar, div.content {
    border-width:          10px;
    border-style:          solid;
    -webkit-border-image:  url(images/borderimage.gif) 10 10 10 10 stretch stretch;
       -moz-border-image:  url(images/borderimage.gif) 10 10 10 10 stretch stretch;
            border-image:  url(images/borderimage.gif) 10 10 10 10 stretch stretch;
}
```

**IE**

`border-image` isn't supported by [IE10 or earlier](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image). Simulating it in IE would require some additional jQuery code and/or modifying the static HTML.

**Options**

The two cleanest approaches are:

1. If it's not essential to have the border images in IE10, then only provide them for browsers that support the `border-image` style (progressive enhancement).
2. If it is essential to have the border images in IE10, then since a different approach would be needed for IE10, you may as well use the same approach for the Chrome and Firefox as well (and not use the `border-image` style at all). This way you don't have to maintain two different implementations of this on the same website.

Comment: Thanks, adding the border-style fixed it, and quite frankly, IE10 isn't a good browser, so I'm happy with just giving it a simple black border.